# opencart image uploading error in admin panel

Tags: opencart, image-upload

i am working in opencart 2.3.0.2
Whenever i upload product image every time i am getting error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 22464 bytes) in /XXXX/XXXX/public_html/system/library/image.php on line 26
```

my image size is in kb still getting error and i also try
in index.php

```
ini_set("memory_limit",2048);
```

and in php.ini file

```
memory_limit = 128M;
```

still I didn't get any solution. Any help, appreciated.

Comment: don't forget to use the formatting tools next time.

Comment: Some hosting accounts have memory_limit inside them and they ignore the php.ini try looking inside your host for that

Comment: Thank you @Innervisions got solution